# Using Parseval's theorem to solve an integral

Tags: integration, signal-processing, fourier-transform

The question at hand is to use Parseval's theorem to solve the following integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} sinc^4 (kt) dt$$

I understand Parseval's theorem to be:

$$E_g = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g^2(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |G(f)|^2 df $$

I began by doing the obvious and removing the squared such that:

$$g^2(t) = Sinc^4 (kt)$$

$$g(t) = Sinc^2 (kt)$$

Following the table of Fourier transforms in my book, I see that

$B*sinc^2({\pi}Bt)$ has the transform $\Delta(\frac{f}{2B})$. However, I'm stuck at this becuase I'm not sure how I can integrate the $\Delta$. I also feel as though I am overthinking this problem - any assistance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much in advanced!

Comment: Are you having a problem with integrating the triangle function?

Comment: yes. I honestly don't know what to do with it

Answer (score 3):

Using [Parseval's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem#Notation_used_in_engineering_and_physics), we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{sinc}^4(kt)\,dt&=\frac{1}{k}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{sinc}^4(t)\,dt\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi k}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left|\mathscr{F}\left(\text{sinc}^2\right)(\omega)\right|^2\,d\omega
\end{align}$$

where

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}\left(\text{sinc}^2\right)(\omega)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{sinc}^2(t)e^{i\omega t}\,dt\\\\
&=\frac{\pi }{4}\left(|\omega -2|-2|\omega|+|\omega+2|\right)
\end{align}$$

Therefore,

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{sinc}^4(kt)\,dt&=\frac{1}{2\pi k} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\frac{\pi }{4}\left(|\omega -2|-2|\omega|+|\omega+2|\right)\right)^2 \,d\omega\\\\
&=\frac{\pi}{16 k}\int_0^2 \left(4-2\omega \right)^2 \,d\omega\\\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{3k}
\end{align}$$

Comment: (for the step 2 : $sinc(t)$ is the FT of $C 1_{|\omega| < 1}$ hence $sinc(t)^2$ is the FT of $C^2 1_{|\omega| < 1} \ast 1_{|\omega| < 1} $)

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, precisely.  The self-convolution of the rectangle function is indeed a triangle function.  Evidently, the OP has been given that result.

Comment: Also, is it a known that $$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}\left(\text{sinc}^2\right)(\omega)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{sinc}^2(t)e^{i\omega t}\,dt\\\\
&=\frac{\pi }{4}\left(|\omega -2|-2|\omega|+|\omega+2|\right)
\end{align}$$ ?

Comment: @BillyThorton In the OP, it states that the Fourier Transform of $\text{sinc}^2$ is a triangle function.  We can derive that result as user1952009 stated.

Comment: @user1952009 Yes.  +1 for your comment. Much appreciated. -Mark

Comment: Ah that makes sense now. Thank you so much!!! One last question:
$\frac{1}{2\pi k}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left|\mathscr{F}\left(\text{sinc}^2\right)(\omega)\right|^2\,d\omega$
makes sense because when you pull out the squared you are also pulling out a $\frac{1}{2\pi}$?

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  Pleased that things make sense now.  The $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ is a scale factor in [Parseval's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem#Notation_used_in_engineering_and_physics) when the FT is defined as in this solution.

Comment: yes, since he wrote $f$ he probably uses the unitary definition of the Fourier transform, which is  preferable (even if it adds some $2\pi$ constants in the functions) since the parseval identity and the Fourier inversion are easy to remember

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, maybe easier.
$$ I(k)=\int_\mathbb{R}\text{sinc}(kt)^4\,dt = \frac{1}{k}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)^4}{x^4}\,dx \tag{1}$$
but $\sin(x)^4 = \frac{3}{8}-\frac{1}{2}\cos(2x)+\frac{1}{8}\cos(4x)$ by De Moivre's formula, so by applying integration by parts three times:
$$ I(k) = \frac{1}{6k}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\frac{d^3}{dx^3}\sin(x)^4}{x}\,dx = \frac{1}{6k}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{8\sin(4x)-4\sin(2x)}{x}\,dx\tag{2}$$
and:

> $$ I(k) = \frac{(8-4)\pi}{6k} = \color{red}{\frac{2\pi}{3k}}\tag{3}$$

follows.

Comment: @FelixMarin: thank you, now fixed.

Comment: (so by applying integration by parts 3 times)