# From FT deduce the value of $\int_0^{\infty} {\sin^4 x \over x^4} dx$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

We have the function $$f\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
1+x, & -1\leq x\leq0\\
1-x, & 0\leq x\leq1\\
0, & \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}
 $$
we computed its Fourier transform:

$$\hat f(t) = {\sin^2(\pi t) \over \pi^2 t^2}$$

we are asked to deduce the value of the integral

$$\int_0^{\infty} {\sin^4 x \over x^4} dx$$

how to do this?

Help is much appreciated

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1815243/using-parsevals-theorem-to-solve-an-integral/1815862?noredirect=1#comment3723697_1815862

Comment: [Duplicate of](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1815243/using-parsevals-theorem-to-solve-an-integral/1815267#1815267)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By [Parseval's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem) we have $$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^{4}\left(x\right)}{x^{4}}dx= & \pi\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^{4}\left(\pi t\right)}{\left(\pi t\right)^{4}}dt \\
  = & \pi\int_{-1}^{0}\left(1+x\right)^{2}dx+\pi\int_{0}^{1}\left(1-x\right)^{2}dx \\
 = & \frac{2}{3}\pi
\end{align}
 $$ and now observe that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^{4}\left(x\right)}{x^{4}}dx=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^{4}\left(x\right)}{x^{4}}dx$$ so

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^{4}\left(x\right)}{x^{4}}dx=\frac{\pi}{3}.$$